# Can I change a column values to RowNames in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a column imported from an .csv file which contains the rows as "Dates". Is it possible to import these values as rownames to the table in matlab?

What i have done is created a variable to import these dates which are mixed numeric values. How can I import these values to my table as rownames?

Since RowNames is type double how can i 'import' char dates?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: In the documentation of `table`- https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html, on the first example, there are char type RawNames. It may help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the import assistant. 
If you go to Home tab > Import Data. Select the file.

You can choose the type of imported data: Table (with names), column vectors (separated variables with those names), ...

If you want to know how that is coded, you can go to the "Import Selection" button and click "generate script". It creates a script where you can see the necessary code to do the same thing that the assistant can do.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you please advise how i can label the rows also. I am using time series thus need to add dates and time to the rows.

Comment: In the same "import assistant" you can select the time of data. Take a look at the previous photo. Under column 'N' there is a field 'DateU...' this is my DATEUTC, and under the name MATLAB establishes the type, in this case 'TEXT'. But if you click that field you can choose  'Number', 'Categorical', ... 'date: dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss' or if you want, a custom format. 

For example, if you column only has day, month and hour, like: '21/11 - 21' you can set your custom format like: 'dd/MM - HH'

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what the format of your table/the original data is , but as I came here looking for an answer to this problem I figure I'll share what I found based on what I think you mean (old question I know).

Consider a table of the following form saved to a csv file (has no RowNames)

```
B = table({'01/Jan' ;'02/Jan'; '03/Jan' ;'04/Jan'; '05/Jan'},[23;5;17;40;19],[38;43;45;40;49],...
'VariableNames',{'Date','AverageScore' 'MaxScore'})
```

You can specify that the first column should be the rownames when you read in the table using

```
myTable = readtable('tableB.csv','ReadRowNames',true)
```

see documentation on [readtable](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html) under the heading Create Table from Spreadsheet Including Row Names

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to do this.

**1. During Import (`readtable`)**

```
opts = detectImportOptions($File_Path);
opts.RowNamesColumn = $Column_Index;
Table = readtable($File_Path, opts);
```

The second row of code may be different depends on the type of file you aim to read. For example, if your file is kind of "Spreadsheet" whose import option `opts` should be `SpreadsheetImportOptions`, then the second row of code should be changed to

```
opts.RowNamesRange = $Column_Index or '$Column_Index1:$Column_Index2'
```

For the other two file types: "Text files" whose import option is `DelimitedTextImportOptions` and "Fixed-width text files" with import option as `FixedWidthImportOptions`. The original one (set `RowNamesColumn`) works.

If you cannot tell which type your file belongs to. You can find answer in `opts` after you run `opts = detectImportOptions($File_Path);` (or just directly delete the semicolon and run it)

**2. Convert Table (`table`)**

```
Table = readtable($File_Path); % Ignore this if you got target table already
Table.Properties.RowNames = string(Table{:,$Column_Index});
```